# How to successfully pause game in Corona SDK?

Tags: coronasdk

Im trying to learn Corona through someone else's sample code. So this is a game like fruit ninja, and im trying to put a pause/resume function on it. Now since the code uses physics, i thought that i should use physics.pause and physics.start and i also paused the timer for the objects. It does freezes the screen, but when you swipe at one of the objects on the screen(fruits), it still breaks into two. How do i stop that? So i guess the pause works a little, because it stops the fruits from coming up. Thanks so much for the people who will answer my question. Ive read a few forums on here and you guys seem to really know what youre doing. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your line here:

```
Runtime:addEventListener("touch", drawSlashLine)
```

Is it possible to remove this event listener in your pause, and re-add it into your resume?

Actually that will just stop you from drawing. You need to loop through all objects and remove their touch event listener.

Alternatively set a global variable to true when paused, and in chopFruit function check it, and do nothing if its set to true.

Comment: hey if your problem is solved please accept the answer by checking it and for others to have a reference if they encounter the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You should add code similar to the following:

```
if gameIsActive then
    gameIsActive = false
    physics.pause()
        Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame",moveEnemy)

leftarrow:removeEventListener( "touch", moveLeft )

end
```

Then on resume, you should add the event listeners back.